# How can I make my app an option in the assist app settings?

Tags: android

According to my research, starting in API 23, you can change the app you use when you hold down the home button. Any ideas on how to get my assistant as an option? Thanks in advance. (The issue is I cannot find code to make this work)

The setting is usually at Settings/Apps (or App Manager)/Configure apps (three dots icon)/Assist & voice input/assist app

Comment: Please clarify the question and what you tried still now?. Also post your code snippet for that.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I can't find examples.

Comment: I found the Android 6.0 APIs page helpful if you find Assist API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a personal assistant just like the Google Now on Tap using the Assist API starting Android 6.0. The official developer (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html) guide tells exactly how you should implement it.

Comment: Can you please include the code required for this, I am not an expert on understanding documentation.

Comment: overview of implementing your own assist app: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant#implementing_your_own_assistant example code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/tests/VoiceInteraction/